# Getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: continue must be inside loop" in the following code

Tags: javascript, loops

```
document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    const inputTags = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
    const textArea = document.querySelector('textarea');

    inputTags.splice(inputTags.length, 0, textArea);


    let output = "";

    inputTags.forEach((input) => {
        if(input.type == "checkbox" && input.checked == true ) {
            output += input.nextElementSibling.textContent; 
            output += input.checked; 
            output += "\n"; 
            continue;
        } else if(input.type == "radio" && input.checked == true) {
            if(input.nextElementSibling.textContent == "I have money and can pay for this") {
                output += input.nextElementSibling.textContent.toLowerCase();
                output += "\n"; 
            }
        } else {
            output += input.nextElementSibling.textContent; 
            output += input.value;
        }
    })

    alert(output);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `continue` outside a loop. A `forEach` call does not count as being inside a loop. Instead just return or make sure that nothing else happens before the function completes.

Seems like you could just remove that `continue` and everything would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

you are not in a loop, you are in a function (forEach), so use **return** instead of **continue**